# How to rewrite the following sync code to async?

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to rewrite this with using `async_ajax()`?

```
function some_event_handler () {
  if (condition) {
    sync_ajax();
    ajax_dependent_code1;
  } else {
    ajax_independent_code;
  }
  ajax_dependent_code2;
}
```

Comment: `ajax_dependent_code2` runs regardless  if the ajax is run or not, so is it really ajax dependent?

Comment: okay, the question is rightful... In `ajax_dependent_code2;` I'm reading a global variable that might be changed by the `sync_ajax()`

Comment: Are you using an ajax library that does support promises?

Comment: Removed salutation: "Thanks in advance", don't do it next time

Answer (score 1):

I did it in the following way:

```
function some_event_handler () {
  async_ajax(callback_function () {
    if (condition) {
      ajax_dependent_code1;
    } else {
      ajax_independent_code;
    }
    ajax_dependent_code2;
  });
}
```

I hope it will be okay...